# How to draw not out of panel borders in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, line, mxml

I want to draw some lines, they must not goes across the panel borders, I don't know how to do that...
Line goes over the panel borders, but I want that line goes into panel and then i would can zoom it.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.graphics.SolidColorStroke;

        import spark.primitives.Line;



        private function drawLine():void 
        {
            var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
            myShape = new Shape() ;


            myShape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x00008B, .75);
            myShape.graphics.moveTo(500, 500);

            myShape.graphics.lineTo(25, 45);
            spr.addChild(myShape);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:Button label="Click" click="drawLine()" />
<s:Panel  y="30" width="400" height="250" layout="vertical" title="Panel" borderColor="#008040" fontFamily="Arial" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="13">

<mx:Text text="Drawing.." fontWeight="bold"/>
        <s:SpriteVisualElement width="500" height="500" id="spr"/>
</s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to put the contents in a `Group` and set [`clipAndEnableScrolling`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#clipAndEnableScrolling).

```
<s:Panel>
    <s:VGroup height="100%" width="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
        <mx:Text text="Drawing.." fontWeight="bold"/>
        <s:SpriteVisualElement width="500" height="500" id="spr"/>            
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Panel>
```